how to get table (Cont.)
how do i get the table(Cont.) for tables that span across multiple pages
I tried the continued float option but it doesnt seem to work.I only get the "Table" wihtout the (Cont.) in the caption. My preamble is
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{comment}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
%\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric-comp ,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

This is my code
(Table 1)
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\caption{}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
(Table 2)```

